# Surya Arghya ingredients mentioned in Ramayan and other scriptures?

Tags: ramayana, worship, surya

Does anyone know what eight ingredients are mentioned in the Ramayana for Surya Arghya? I am also curious what other scriptures say about ingredients in Surya Arghya so mentioning those are welcome as well.

**Extra info after reading all comments below:**

The reason why I have been asking for eight ingredients is because its being told in the following video: [Surya Arghya Daan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9WPI2V5eE4)

Also after researching its origin I came across some books(not scriptures) mentioning it. The following two books say something about eight ingredients for Surya Arghya: 
[Book 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=0U2QRpDv2KMC&pg=PA732&dq=surya%20arghya%20eight%20ingredients&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=surya%20arghya%20eight%20ingredients&f=false) 
[Book 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=y2noBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT703&lpg=PT703&dq=turmeric%20arghya%20ramayana&source=bl&ots=zxXDotfPJ4&sig=ACfU3U2pNp0zFl_AF9O5f0UzSW5Kix46yA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=turmeric%20arghya%20ramayana&f=false)

I just want to know what the eight ingredients are and also where it is being mentioned in the scriptures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following verse in KulArnava Tantram's 17th chapter. It is talking about **AshtAnga Arghya** - the eight ingredients of an Arghya (in general).

> SiddhArtham akshtainjava kushAgram tila meva cha |
>  Javam gandhah
>   phalam pushpam ashtAnga arghyam prakirtitah ||
>
> White mustard seeds, (a kind of) puffed rice, tips of Kusa/Darva
>   grass, sesame seeds (Til), barley (Java), sandal paste/powder (Chandan), fruits (Phala) and
>   flowers (Pushpa) -- these 8 things are known as the ingredients of an Arghya.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 17.96**

Note that it is generally talking about the 8 ingredients of an Arghya. So, it should apply to Surya Arghya too.

UPDATE:

Another reference, this time specifically about Surya Arghya, is found in the following Gupta DikshA Tantram verses as quoted in [Shaktananda Tarangini's](http://www.shivashakti.com/shaktanan.htm) 2nd chapter:

> Apah kshiram kushAgrAni ghritam dadhi tathA madhu |
>  RaktAni
>   karavirAni tathA raktancha chandanam |
>  **AshtAnga esho koharghyo vai
>   bhAnave parikirtitah ||**
>
> Water, milk, Kusa-tips, Ghee, curd, honey, red Karavi flower and red
>   sandal - These are known as the 8 ingredients of Arghya of BhAnu (or
>   Surya).

So, while the previous list is generally applicable the 2nd list is specifically for Surya.

Comment: Arghya means the water that is offered for washing hands (in a shodasopachara puja), similarly Padyam means water for washing feet .. @ParthaBanerjee Here OP  is simply asking what are the 8 ingredients which I hv given

Comment: http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=अर्घ्य&lang=sans&action=Search

Comment: Yes probably they are mixed .. but now a days only Ganges water offered @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: See my update @ParthaBanerjee Both quotes are on ashtanga Arghya but the last one is specifically on Surya Arghya

Comment: Yes, its THE answer

Comment: Yes, but I am still curious if it is also written in the Ramayana.

Comment: Ok but u asked whether it is mentioned in scriptures or not and I hv given references from them. @shanayan